# How to solve linear equations with parametrization?

Tags: python, numpy, linear-equation

I am trying to solve my equasions this way:

```
a = np.array([[1,2,4,1,0,2],[0,1,2,0,0,1],[0,0,0,2,2,0],[0,0,0,0,14,4],[0,0,0,0,0,-2]])
b = np.array([3,0,1,0,14])
x = np.linalg.solve(a,b)
```

However, as they are not full ranked there is no one solution, but instead endless solutions. Usually I would simply insert a parameter, like x3 = t when solving this. Then I have a solution where x2 and x1 can also contain t. But how can I tell python to solve it this way? Or at least tell it that x3 is t and to continue using that?

I know there is the leastsquares way, but that's not what I'm looking for.

Edit: The solution will look something like that: `x6 == -7 && x5 == 2 && x4 == -(3/2) && x2 == 7 - 2 x3 && x1 == 9/2` - made with Mathematica. Just want to know how to achieve the same result in python.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using [SymPy](https://www.sympy.org/en/index.html),

```
import numpy as np
import sympy as sym

a = np.array([[1,2,4,1,0,2],[0,1,2,0,0,1],[0,0,0,2,2,0],[0,0,0,0,14,4],[0,0,0,0,0,-2]])
b = np.array([3,0,1,0,14])
num_equations, num_variables = a.shape

x = sym.symarray('x', num_variables)
solution = sym.solve([sym.Eq(ax-b) for ax, b in zip(np.dot(a, x), b)])
print(solution)
```

yields

```
{x_5: -7, x_4: 2, x_3: -3/2, x_1: -2*x_2 + 7, x_0: 9/2}
```

Answer (score 1):

There's a math side of this and a programming side of this. On the math side, it's important to note that if ax=b has multiple solutions, then those solutions are {y + b1 * t1 + b_2 * t_2 + ... + bN * tN | t1, ..., tN in the real numbers} where y is any solution to ax=b (such as the least-squares solution) and b1, ..., bN are basis vectors for the null space of a. On the programming side, `np.linalg.lstsq` gets a least squares solution, and `scipy.linalg.null_space` gets the null space. One way you could put these together to get output similar to what you want is as follows.

```
import numpy as np
import scipy.linalg
import sys


def print_parameterized_form(a, b):
    one_solution = np.linalg.lstsq(a, b, rcond=None)[0]
    null_space_basis = scipy.linalg.null_space(a)
    for i in range(a.shape[1]):
        sys.stdout.write('x{} = {}'.format(i, one_solution[i]))
        for j in range(null_space_basis.shape[1]):
            sys.stdout.write(' + ({}) * t{}'.format(null_space_basis[i, j], j))
        sys.stdout.write('\n')

a = np.array([[1,2,4,1,0,2],[0,1,2,0,0,1],[0,0,0,2,2,0],[0,0,0,0,14,4],[0,0,0,0,0,-2]])
b = np.array([3,0,1,0,14])

print_parameterized_form(a, b)
```

This should give you something like this:

```
x0 = 4.500000000000011 + (-3.5160449919006082e-15) * t0
x1 = 1.4000000000000128 + (0.8944271909999162) * t0
x2 = 2.7999999999999887 + (-0.4472135954999573) * t0
x3 = -1.499999999999997 + (9.065580383436411e-17) * t0
x4 = 2.0000000000000004 + (4.62652890306841e-18) * t0
x5 = -6.999999999999999 + (1.86607760441072e-16) * t0
```

Comment: I see, but that's not ideal for non-integer matrizes. It works for me, but I have to wonder why something as big as python/numpy/scipy doesn't have a way to do this yet, unlike mathematica. Are these kinds of problems not often encountered in the cases where you use python? Or are other tools used then instead?